# how to start fme workbench from c#

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application, fme

I'm using 2017.0 fme workbench version, I'm trying to start fme directly from c#. I have a windows application that calls cmd.exe and from there I call fme and pass some parameters (command line), there's any way that I can start fme from c# without using cmd.exe?

Thanks

Comment: What is 'fme'? I'm sorry if i'm missing something obvious but I really can't associate it...

Comment: @Zegar See [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fme).

Comment: _"any way that I can start fme from c# without using cmd.exe?"_ Yes, there is. Start it directly with Process.Start. There are plenty of related questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of questions are easy to look up in the safe community. I Found [this](https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D54Q000080hSB6SAM/launch-fme-using-visual-basic) answer and addopted it to your specific question.

Your question has two parts:

1. How to execute an external program from .NET: There are lots of examples to be found with Google, such as [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbfaq/archive/2004/05/30/144573.aspx) (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbfaq/archive/2004/05/30/144573.aspx).
2. How to run FME on the command line, specifying published parameters: When executing a workspace inside FME Workbench, scroll to the very top of the log window, where you will see exactly how to re-run the workspace on the command line, with your current user parameters.